# how to only use y axis or lock x and z axis for rotation using the transform.lookat command {unity}

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get enemy behavior figured out, but if the object is larger than me or I can jump over it, it will rotate to look at me and hover or sink in the ground. I want to either set it to only use the y-axis, or lock the x and z axis. I've tried several different methods. but I don't know if the code is incompatible or if I just integrated it wrong, seeing as the code examples I found online where either outdated or as I'm using the transfrom.lookat() command.

[Object rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lypeQ.png)

also if you know how to get the object to "fly" and come down later randomly would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    public Transform player;

    public LayerMask whatIsGround, whatIsPlayer;


    //Patrol
    public Vector3 walkPoint;
    bool walkPointSet;
    public float walkPointRange;

    //Attacking
    public float timeBetweenAttack;
    bool alreadyAttacked;
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float hitPoints;

    //states
    public float sightRange, attackRange;
    public bool playerInSightRange, playerInAttackRange;

    private void Awake()
    {
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //Check sight and attack range
        playerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, whatIsPlayer);
        playerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attackRange, whatIsPlayer);

        if (!playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) Patroling();
        if (playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) ChasePlayer();
        if (playerInSightRange && playerInAttackRange) AttackPlayer();

    }

    private void Patroling()
    {
        if (!walkPointSet) SearchWalkPoint();

        if (walkPointSet)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);

            Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - walkPoint;

            //walk point reached
            if(distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 1f)
            {
                walkPointSet = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SearchWalkPoint()
    {
        float randomZ = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);
        float randomX = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);

        walkPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x + randomX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + randomZ);

        if(Physics.Raycast(walkPoint, -transform.up, 2f, whatIsGround))
        {
            walkPointSet = true;
        }
    }
    private void ChasePlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(player.position);
        transform.LookAt(player);
    }

    private void AttackPlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

        transform.LookAt(player);

        if (!alreadyAttacked)
        {
            Rigidbody rb = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            rb.AddForce(transform.up * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
            alreadyAttacked = true;
            Invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttack);
        }

    }

    private void ResetAttack()
    {
        alreadyAttacked = false;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        hitPoints -= damage;

        if (hitPoints <= 0) Invoke(nameof(DestroyEnemy), 2f);
    }
    private void DestroyEnemy()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Transform.LookAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) has overloads taking any world position `Vector3` as input instead of a target `Transform`.

You can simply make sure that there isn't any position difference in the `Y-axis`.

As long as you have only a position difference in the `XZ` plane you only rotate around `Y`.

E.g. like

```
var playerPos = player.position;
playerPos.y = transform.position.y;
transform.LookAt(playerPos);
```